# `dd` to specific location

Tags: partition, dd

`dd` is a great tool for copying and conversion.

Is there any way by `dd` (or by any other way), to dump the first few bytes from a file to an unmounted partition?

Something like this:

`dd if=hda2.pbr of=/dev/hda2 bs=512 count=1`

The goal, I'm trying to achieve is to copy out the PBR of a partition to file and restore it as and when required. When that partition not required, then I will dump the PBR with some garbage value, so that underlying partition will fail to get mounted

Comment: How does the command you suggested not do exactly what you're asking for? It would appear you're trying to save/restore the partition boot record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your edit, I think you might find the following pretty useful:

```
man wipefs
```

#### DESCRIPTION

> `wipefs`  can  erase  filesystem,  raid  or partition-table signatures *(magic strings)* from the specified device to make the signatures invisible for `libblkid`...

#### OPTIONS

> `-a`, `--all` Erase all available signatures.  The set of erased signatures can be restricted with the `-t` list option.
>
> `-b`, `--backup` Create a signature backup to the file `$HOME/wipefs-<devname>-<offset>.bak`.  For more details see ***EXAMPLES*** section...

#### EXAMPLES

```
wipefs --all --backup /dev/sdb
```

> Erases all signatures from the device `/dev/sdb` and creates a  signature backup file `~/wipefs-sdb-<offset>.bak` for each signature.

```
dd if=~/wipefs-sdb-0x00000438.bak of=/dev/sdb \
    seek=$((0x00000438)) bs=1 conv=notrunc
```

> Restores `ext2` signature from the backup file `~/wipefs-sdb-0x00000438.bak`.

Comment: I had the old version. I just upgraded `wipefs` from 20 to 24 and now it's working as expectation

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can do that. Consider everything in UNIX/Linux a file. So basically its copying from one file to another.

For example you can even copy a text to a partition and read it back without issues.
So your example is perfect.